# Is there a way to set the back button item image in every view controller of a navigation controller by subclassing the navigation controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I want every view controller in my navigation controller to have a custom back button. So far I've been setting it in viewDidLoad of every view controller, but that feels needlessly repetitive.

I tried subclassing `UINavigationController` and in the initializers setting `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` to the custom view. However it never shows up.

How would I accomplish this? Is it possible to use a subclass of `UINavigationController` to set the custom back button?

Comment: You can set appearance attributes universally in AppDelegate. http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-bar-back-butto/

Comment: @AdrianB That only discusses changing the background, not the actual image

Comment: I haven't done it with an image, but I've done it with other attribute properties in projects before. I think you could just tweak the `backIndicatorImage` https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/backItem

Comment: If your NavigationControllers is controlling a UITableViewController, try subclassing those instead